# Space between every result

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, sql

So i'm using this code to view job applications on my site, but it looks kinda messy.
How do I add so it makes a few spaces after every application?

```
<?php      // Make a MySQL Connection
$query = "SELECT * FROM jobs ORDER by username DESC"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo("<tr>");
    echo("<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>");
    echo("<td>" . $row['why'] . "</a></td>");
    echo("<td>" . $row['experience'] . "</td>");
    echo("<td>" . $row['age'] . "</td>");
    echo("<td>" . $row['other'] . "</td></tr>");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap all your `<tr></tr>` tags in a `<table></table>` tag (Otherwise content will be displayed as a plaintext). Also add this CSS inside `<header></header` tag in your file (for example) :

```
<style>
    td{padding: 0 5px;}
</style>
```

It will give every `<td></td>` tag padding-left and padding-right,so they won't be merged.

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/6mCEL/)

Comment: Did not seem to work, I tried playing around with the values.